# IO request queueing

Tags: assembly, io, operating-system

This one is about calls waiting for IO that allow context switching, or non-blocking call models:

1. How exactly are they implemented within the OS?
2. How do the underlying devices work on an instruction level - e.g. the exact CPU instructions for storage and network hardware?
3. How many IO instructions can be pending with a device at a time?
4. How many IO requests can be queued with the OS, e.g. Linux and Windows at a time? Where to look for this info for other OSes?

EDIT: This is both a broad and specific question. Its about IO devices and the CPU, which the OS uses to get the job done - so please answer what you can. Its about memory too because every IO operation has memory involved for data (if not addressing). x86 and/or broadly classified answers would do. For devices you could choose network/storage on x86.

Comment: The question is too broad. Details are quite varying on device type, vendor, exact model, OS kind, used buses, etc. Plaese try to narrow it.

Comment: These implementations differ from OS to OS. For Linux you can look at the kernel source; for Windows you will not get any reliable information at all.

Comment: There are no CPU instructions specific to accessing storage hardware or network hardware on modern CPUs. Some CPUs may have a few a I/O  instructions that can be used to access devices, but many devices can be accessed without using the I/O specific instructions. The CPU places no limit on pending I/O operations. Operating systems generally don't have a fixed limit on pending I/O operations.

Comment: Martin: Thanks. Do you know of any brief documentation of the Linux kernel source?

Comment: Ross: so does everything go in/out character by character, for both block and character devices? Considering every CPU instruction is blocking in itself, what does it mean for a process to wait for IO - is it the multiplexing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1. How exactly are they implemented within the OS?

**Making the request**

Let's see what happen when you invoke a write on a device.

1. You ask your runtime to perform a file write.
2. The runtime in the end invokes a system call.
3. The kernel locate the driver/module associated with the device you wrote into.
4. The driver/module performs its operations and may forward the request to other driver/module.
5. There is a last driver/module that specifically handle the hardware device, record the request and send the write command.

**Putting the task to sleep**
The last driver/module return a status code in order to inform its caller what happened. For the sake of simplicity assume that the return status are only: *Success*, *Fails*, *Pending*.
By returning *Pending* the driver/module informs that the request is ongoing.
The control return from 5. to 2. where the kernel is given the return status of the write.
If it is *Success* or *Error* it return to the user space indicating success or failure. If it is *Pending* however it marks the program as **Waiting for IO** (by using any OS specific method).
This is the key point, a task that is waiting it is not scheduled, even it there is nothing else to do.
While going from 1. to 5. the kernel can (in most OS and only when the driver/module or the kernel itself allow that) be preempted, i.e. interrupted, but the state of the calling task would be *Running* and so it will be rescheduled later, however a waiting task is not scheduled.

**Waiking the task**
When the the hardware is done, it request the CPU attention with an interrupt. The module/driver in 5. set a callback so that it get its code executed when the hardware it manages invokes the CPU attention.
After eventually finalizing the hardware operation, the module/driver inform the kernel that a specific request (previously recorded) is done.
The kernel know which task did the request and change its state to *Running*, thereby waking it.

## 2. How do the underlying devices work on an instruction level - e.g. the exact CPU instructions for storage and network hardware?

To handle a network device you mostly use moving instructions.
To handle a storage device you mostly use moving instructions.
To handle a *[insert device type here]* device you mostly use moving instructions.

In a computer everything is just a move of data. You move 09h and 41h in a multiplication ALU and you get 249h, you move 09h and 41h in a display memory and you get a colored *A*. You move 09h and 41h in a timer register and you get a beep sound.

System can be very different but the principle is the same. You move data to and from location identified by address. In most system this is the same as writing to RAM, however every system may have peculiarities, such as different kind of set of address accessed with different instructions (these are commonly referred as address spaces, example are: memory address space, IO address space, bus address space, PCI configuration address space, NUMA address space, ...).

An x86 CPU itself is aware of two address space: Memory Address space (up to 48 bit nowadays) and IO Address space (16 bit).
The first is accessed with any memory instruction (like if you were accessing global variables), the second one with specific instruction that has mnemonic that start with `in` and `out`.
Note however that IO address space is a vestigial space of the early days of IA32, new devices nowadays don't use it.

## 3. How many IO instructions can be pending with a device at a time?

## 4. How many IO requests can be queued with the OS, e.g. Linux and Windows at a time? Where to look for this info for other OSes?

If you mean actively pending, i.e. executed by the hardware concurrently, then this is usually one or little more.
Most controllers (like AHCI, XHCI, EHCI and so on) handle data structures that let the device to enqueue more than one requests, however they are handled one at a time. Usually there is no limit (but the available memory to describe the requests) but this is hardware specific.
Other controllers, like SCSI ones, can handle more than one command at a time.

The OS handles a software queue of request too, so again potentially infinite and limited only by the available memory.
Usually however the limit is a reasonable number.
Alex D. answer has more details on this.

For Windows, the DDK help cites

> Except for file system drivers, the I/O manager associates a device queue object (for queuing IRPs) with each device object that a driver creates.

However it doesn't specify if there is a limit and in the programming interface I found no API to specify a limit on the number of requests.
So it is up to the driver coder to eventually impose an upper bound.
I don't know if Windows has a limit per sé (I presume it has not).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It does clear some doubts. Would be great if you could explain exactly what happens from top to bottom when multiple send()s are issued by different applications using sockets, on the same network card. Please also include the details of the underlying notification that wakes up the processes after the send() completes. x86 would do.

Comment: @samofoz Sorry for being late. Take a look [here](http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/understanding-tcp-ip-network-stack/) for details on how the TCP/IP stack works on linux. For a concrete case of a NIC (Network card) types of interrupts you can look at page 13 of [this datasheet](http://realtek.info/pdf/rtl8139d.pdf). As you can see, the kernel can be notified when a packet has been successfully transmitted or received. This two documents are enough to get the complete picture. if you need explanation on a specific subject just post a question ;)

Comment: Thanks for getting me so close. Figure 8-9 in the first document is what I am after. Its a bit lengthy and not as simple. Why does the "driver requests packet receiving" - this amounts to polling? What I understand is that for the receives, the NIC first writes the packet to the ring buffer and then interrupts the CPU. For the sends, the CPU writes the packet to another ring and interrupts the NIC, and when the NIC is done it interrupts back the CPU with the context. This understanding does not seem enough to understand some complicated text.

Comment: @samofoz action 2 of figure 9 is not done for every packet, it is done only when the RX buffer has been filled or the very first time. So in general the sequence is: Create the RX buffer the first time, tell the NIC where the buffer is and etc, CPU get interrupted by the NIC for every packed received, when the buffer is full, reset it and tell it to the NIC

Comment: Ok. I tried to read the second (realtek) document. Do these vendors (e.g. x86 peripherals) include a programming guide, sample programs? How do people learn to program them?

Comment: @samofoz The datasheet usually are documented enough, a sample program would be problematic as it would be OS dependent. Anyway the datasheet from RealTek has been stripped down, I cannot find the complete one, recently the company started to ask for NDA signatures. A very complete one is this [one](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/embedded/products/networking/82599-10-gbe-controller-datasheet.html) from Intel.

Comment: Getting closer :). Page 41 and 42 has the matter in question. Any idea where they could be described in detail, in a simple language, preferably with some sample code?

Comment: @samofoz All I can find is the Linux source, [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/ixgbe/ixgbe_82599.c#L2292) the C structure with all the operation the module implements. It is no easy to follow what it is happening without the datasheet in mind but it the only *"program"* I can find

Comment: feels like the most complicated embedded systems excercise. Any idea who does courses that cover such things?

Answer (score 3):

1. Broadly, a blocking I/O call does this: 1) put a process/thread on a list of processes/threads which are waiting for I/O to complete, 2) mark it as non-runnable, and 3) invoke a context switch. Since the thread which made the blocking call is now marked as non-runnable, the OS' scheduler will never schedule it to run on the CPU, *until* the I/O operation completes, and the thread is marked as runnable again. That is what "blocking" actually means.

   Linux has an interface for non-blocking I/O calls, which works roughly like this: your program first makes a system call to create an "asynchronous I/O context". This is an object which includes a queue for notification events generated when an I/O operation completes. The kernel passes back an AIO context identifier which your program uses when making subsequent calls. Then, when you want to do some I/O, you make another system call to "submit" an async I/O operation for execution. You can submit as many of these as you like. As they complete, notifications will accumulate in your AIO context's event queue. Later, whenever you want, you make another syscall to retrieve the notifications from that queue.

   (Interestingly, although Linux has supported these system calls for some time now, they are still not used by Glibc! Glibc implements non-blocking I/O by internally spawning worker threads and doing blocking I/O operations in the worker threads!)
2. There are basically 3 cases. On x86, there are `IN` and `OUT` instructions which are used to transfer 1/2/4 bytes to or from hardware devices. x86 has a special 16-bit address space for "I/O ports" which are accessed by these instructions. (I don't know if any other architectures also have a special I/O address space or not.) Even on x86, though, not all hardware devices are mapped into that I/O address space. Some use the regular memory address space. In that case, you can transfer data to/from them using ordinary `MOV` instructions, or any other instruction which accesses memory. The 3rd case is when DMA (direct memory access) is used. Basically, you use one of the 2 previously mentioned methods to send some kind of command to a hardware device, telling it: "transfer X bytes directly to RAM, starting from address Y". Then the device sends the requested data directly through the system bus and stores it in RAM, without any intervention from the CPU. When it is finished, generally it will raise an interrupt to let you know.
3. This is completely device-dependent. There is no general answer.
4. Well, here is the closest thing to an answer which I can give you, for Linux. (Don't ask me about other OSs.) In Linux, each storage device has its own queue of outstanding I/O requests. Each of those queues has a variable called `nr_requests`, which is the maximum number of outstanding I/O requests which it will hold. You can find what the value is for your hard drive by printing out this pseudo-file: `/sys/block/<DEVICE>/queue/nr_requests`. The default seems to be 128. From reading the source, it seems that 128 is also the maximum (?).

Afterword: If you are thinking of writing some super high-performance I/O-heavy server application, or something, BENCHMARK on all OSs and hardware platforms which you are interested in! You can write a couple of simple test programs which spawn a bunch of threads (make the number configurable) and initiate a (configurable) number of I/O operations, at a (configurable) rate per second. Observe how long it takes for them to all finish, how the server responds while the test is running, and how many operations error out.